# What is the identity of in - "after" or "within"?

Tags: prepositions

This is really controversial in a lot of countries where English is not a native language.

**I will be there in 5 minutes.**

Identity A: I will be there after 5 minutes.

Identity B: I will be there within 5 minutes.

or

"in" is different from A or B and has its own something (like nuance difference) ?

Comment: @YosefBaskin, Thanks for the comment. "in" is the opposite of "out" so "in" is close to "within" ?

Comment: @Brandon Have you looked up the prepositions *in, within* and *after*? What did you find?

Comment: I know in, after, within. But in is taught here my country as "after" in case of "in ten minutes,,,something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience as a native speaker is:

I will be there within five minutes = I will arrive there at or before a time five minutes from now.

I will be there in five minutes = I will arrive there at a time five minutes from now.

I will be there after five minutes = I will arrive there at or after a time five minutes from now.

Others may reasonably think that *at or before* and *at or after* may be replaced by *before* or *after* respectively. But the difference is small, depending on how precisely time is measured.